# Apache Ignite ArrayList write through RDBMS

Tags: ignite

I have cache object structure in the below format,
key,List

How can the CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory be used in keyfields of Ignite configuration. Can you provide an example?

Comment: POJO store will unlikely to be able to convert your list to value. You may use a custom cache store and keep these lists as arrays in value.

Answer (score 1):

The `CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory` is largely designed to mirror the structure of your database table in Ignite. You don't mention which database you're using, but it's unlikely that it has a list datatype.

If you want to use the `CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory` you'll need to normalise your cache structure in Ignite.

Alternatively, you can [write your own cache store](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/custom-cache-store) that will perform the mapping.